# InvalidRequest moving DriveItem between Drives

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to move a `DriveItem` located in the root drive of a parent SharePoint site to a child sub-site.

Parent site:
`mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/Graph` - List: Documents

Child Site
`mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/Graph/SubwebA` - List: Documents

I am using the Microsoft Graph SDK v3.25.0:

```
var client = GetGraphClient();
var destDriveItem = new DriveItem
{
  ParentReference = new ItemReference
  {
    DriveId = destDriveID,
    Id = destDriveFolderID
  }
};

var response = await client
  .Drives[driveID]
  .Items[sourceDriveItemID]
  .Request()
  .UpdateAsync(destDriveItem);
```

All IDs are valid but `UpdateAsync` returns this error:

```
ServiceException: Code: invalidRequest
Message: Requested move requires an async response, add 'Prefer: respond-async' to allow
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        date: 2021-03-04T15:44:38
        request-id: 2aa656e2-fc4b-4314-846b-b62680a15ece
        client-request-id: 2aa656e2-fc4b-4314-846b-b62680a15ece
        ClientRequestId: 2aa656e2-fc4b-4314-846b-b62680a15ece

   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.DriveItemRequest.UpdateAsync(DriveItem driveItemToUpdate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GraphToM365Test.Program.MoveDriveItemToDestinationAndBack(String sourceDriveItemId) in C:\Dev\StratusApps\GraphToM365Test\GraphToM365Test\Program.cs:line 166
   at GraphToM365Test.Program.MainAsync(String[] args) in C:\Dev\StratusApps\GraphToM365Test\GraphToM365Test\Program.cs:line 62
```

The same code works if I move the `DriveItem` between two `Drives` (Document Libraries) in the same site.

The issue is probably related to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2890) (although that is for moving in the same site)

Answer (score 1):

This is an unsupported action. [From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp):

> Items cannot be moved between Drives using this request.

Instead, you need to make two calls:

1. [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) the file to the new location
2. [Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) the file from the old location

```
var client = GetGraphClient();

var parentReference = new ItemReference
{
  DriveId = destDriveID,
  Id = destDriveFolderID
};

var copyResponse = await client
  .Drives[driveID]
  .Items[sourceDriveItemID]
  .Copy(name, parentReference)
  .Request()
  .PostAsync();

var deleteResponse = await client
  .Drives[driveID]
  .Items[sourceDriveItemID]
  .Request()
  .DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: 1) I'm actually able to move files between different document libraries in the same web, so I don't see why they say moving files between Drives isn't supported.


2) Re: the Copy() - It is PostAsync() to end the command - the latest stable for Microsoft.Graph v3.25.0 doesn't have UpdateAsync() on IDriveItemCopyRequest. - Also there is a bug in the SDK for Copy in that the Copy Response is always a null reference so you can't get to the copy monitor to see if it succeeded and what the new DriveItem id is.

Comment: Since the documentation clearly states that moving files between two drives is not supported and you're attempt is failing, it seems fairly straightforward.